# Remove ?= from an AJAX GET call

Tags: ajax, url, parameters, get

I have an ajax call such as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/query/",
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    data: {
        "" : url,
    },
    cache: false,
    //...
});
```

whereas: url: "/query/
is a clean URL.

When I make the request i get an URL such as:

http://domain.net/api/query/?=www.whatever.com&_=1434580542713

how could I remove the "?=" section in order to get an URL such as:

http://domain.net/api/query/www.whatever.com&_=1434580542713

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: "/query/"+url, dataType: 'script', cache: true, data: {}, cache: false,
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that you should escape characters if `url` contains query arguments as those may cause problems.